# How to group all children's/members of a hierarchy using Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, grouping, hierarchy, teradata, recursive-query

I have data for many diff. set of hierarchy in  a table like child-parent relationship and I need to group all individual hierarchy.

eg: all members of a particular hierarchy will be in a group.

```
**Input**
party   related_party
1       2
1       3
3       4
3       5
5       6
6       7
7       8
7       16
8       9
9       11
9       12

**Output**
party   group
1       g1
2       g1
3       g1
4       g1  
5       g1
6       g1
7       g1
8       g1
9       g1
10      g1
11      g1
12      g1
16      g1
```

Currently I have doing a left join of same table 3 times to trace data till 7 level.

```
sel columns
table a 
left join table b
on a.related_party=b.party
left join table c
on b.related_party=c.party;
```

Need to trace till the end of the hierarchy. So, if anyone has any other technique please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a hierarchy, you got a "directed graph". You might try removing the direct links first and then traverse the hierarchy. But you must be able to determine a root.

To prevent cycles you need to create a path showing your previous parties.

```
-- remove duplicates: A-B & B-A
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE tab AS (
SELECT DISTINCT party , related_party
FROM tab_org t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT * FROM tab_org t2
  WHERE t1.related_party = t2.party
    AND t1.party = t2.related_party
    AND t1.related_party < t2.related_party
)
AND related_party <> party
) WITH DATA
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
;

-- now use the cleaner data
WITH RECURSIVE cte 
AS
 (
   SELECT party, related_party, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY party) AS grp, CAST(TRIM(party) AS VARCHAR(10000)) AS PATH, 1 AS lvl
   FROM tab AS t
   WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
      SELECT * FROM tab AS t2
      WHERE t.party = t2.related_party
    )
   UNION ALL
   SELECT tab.party,tab.related_party,  grp, 
      cte.PATH || '.' || TRIM(tab.party), cte.lvl + 1
   FROM cte JOIN tab
   ON tab.party = cte.related_party
         -- if new party is already in path it's a cycle
   WHERE '.'||cte.PATH||'.' NOT LIKE '%.'||TRIM(tab.party)||'.%'
     AND cte.lvl < 10  -- just in case, might be removed
 )
SELECT  * 
FROM cte
ORDER BY path
```

This will work if there are no cycles, otherwise it's more complicated. Depending on your actual data you might need a final `DISTINCT`.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I modified the code little bit to get my desired output. Group name will be the minimum party of a particular hierarchy.     `WITH RECURSIVE cte 
AS
 (
   SELECT party, min(party) OVER (partition BY party) AS grp
   FROM tab AS t
   WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
      SELECT * FROM tab AS t2
      WHERE t.party = t2.related_party
    )
   GROUP BY party
    UNION ALL
   SELECT related_party, grp
   FROM cte JOIN tab ON tab.party = cte.party
 )
SELECT * 
FROM cte
ORDER BY 2,1`

Comment: I have the input data like this [link](http://www.digitalcrunch.in/uploads/Capture.JPG). Now I am removing the reverse set & one to one set from the input using `sel DISTINCT CR1.p,CR1.rp
from  s1dsgedw.cgr AS CR1
INNER JOIN  s1dsgedw.cgr AS CR2
ON CR1.p = CR2.rp
AND CR1.rp > CR2.rp;`and keeping the first set only. After that if I use cte to group all elements by using the logic as you suggested. I am getting two groups.  Just want to know the logic/code to group all elements of the hierarchy in this case & if data is cyclic how to tackle it.

Comment: @Biti: You don't have a hierarchy, you got a "directed graph". There's no root (why it's 1 & 3 and not 7&8 in your link?). I just noticed that my query is wrong, I'll modify it & ad the cycle detection.

Comment: Yes, it's a directed graph sorry for the confusion. I was trying to build the graph starting from 1 & 3 so I was mentioning it as root. So, can you please suggest how we can group all elements (all levels) of a directed graph using recursive sql as shown in output [link](http://www.digitalcrunch.in/uploads/Capture.JPG)

Comment: @Biti: I don't know how to do that, but recursion is probably not a good way as you can't remove unneded rows before the final Select. Loops in a Stored Procedure should be more efficient. There are lots of hits on SO when you search for *directed graph [sql]*